# React <Helmet> is not updating the meta

Tags: reactjs, meta

I have created a react app with around 10 components. I have added meta tag using Helmet.
But when I inspect source from browser, but meta tag shows some random imdb the rock type thing.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
<Helmet>
   <meta charSet="utf-8" />
   <title>My Title</title>
   <link name="description" content="some test description" />
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot inspect meta tags from html source, because:

- html source is static content that javascript cannot touch
- helmet will create meta tags for you after react javascript has been executed

If you want to check meta tags:

- Use "Element" tab in developer tool instead of inspect source
- Use console to check if meta tags exists:

For example, open developer console and you can find `link` tag as follows:

```js
document.querySelector("link[name=description]");
```

Comment: yes, this works and shows me the correct meta description. But if I share the link with someone in social, the preview title and description doesn't show it. It shows the same random imdb title and description. how can I solve this?

Comment: Which social media are you talking?

Comment: It's not only about social media. If you preview the description in anywhere, it could be facebook, slack etc. It shows random imdb data.